# InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class

Tags: android, xml, view

I want to create custom view with a need to change background res according to different situations.

***My CustomViewClass:***

```
public class MessageCloudView extends LinearLayout{

private enum State {
    STABLE, CHECKED, HOVERED, RESEND, ERROR;
}

/**
 * 0 - stable view background
 * 1 - checked_background
 * 2 - hovered_background
 * 3 - resend_background
 */

private State currentState, prevState;
private int[] res;

public MessageCloudView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context, null);
}

public MessageCloudView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this.currentState = State.STABLE;
    this.res = new int[4];

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MessageCloudView, 0, 0);
    try {
        res[0] = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MessageCloudView_stable_background, 0);
        res[1] = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MessageCloudView_checked_background, 0);
        res[2] = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MessageCloudView_hovered_background, 0);
        res[3] = a.getInteger(R.styleable.MessageCloudView_resend_background, 0);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
    setBackgroundResource(res[0]);
}

public MessageCloudView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context, attrs);
}

public MessageCloudView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    this.prevState = this.currentState;
    if(pressed){
        this.currentState = State.HOVERED;
    } else {
        this.currentState = this.prevState;
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
    onDrawableCheck();
}


@Override
public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    this.prevState = this.currentState;
    if(selected){
        this.currentState = State.HOVERED;
    } else {
        this.currentState = this.prevState;
    }
    super.setSelected(selected);
    onDrawableCheck();
}

private void onDrawableCheck(){
    if(this.currentState == State.STABLE) setBackgroundResource(res[0]);
    else if(this.currentState == State.CHECKED)  setBackgroundResource(res[0]);
    else if(this.currentState == State.HOVERED) setBackgroundResource(res[0]);
    else if(this.currentState == State.RESEND) setBackgroundResource(res[0]);
    else if(this.currentState == State.ERROR) setBackgroundResource(res[0]);
}

public void setResent(boolean isResent){
    if(isResent) this.currentState = State.RESEND;
    else this.currentState = State.STABLE;
    onDrawableCheck();
}

public void setError(boolean isError){

}
```

}

***attrs*** file has:

```
<declare-styleable name="MessageCloudView">
    <attr name="stable_background" format="integer" />
    <attr name="checked_background" format="integer" />
    <attr name="hovered_background" format="integer" />
    <attr name="resend_background" format="integer" />
</declare-styleable>
```

in xml file:

```
 <custom.MessageCloudView
        android:id="@+id/ll_message_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:minWidth="65dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        prop:stable_background="@drawable/cloud_messages_contact_document_1080"
        prop:checked_background="@drawable/cloud_messages_contact_document_1080_selected_06"
        prop:hovered_background="@drawable/cloud_messages_contact_document_1080_selected_06"
        prop:resend_background="@drawable/cloud_messages_user_document_1080_red"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">
```

But when I'm trying to inflate my view in adapter by: 

`inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_messages_item_me, parent, false);`

### Error

I get an Error, i think it's because i made something wrong in custom view:

```
   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class custom.MessageCloudView
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
      at list_adapters.ChatMessagesAdapter.inflateNewView(ChatMessagesAdapter.java:142)
      at list_adapters.ChatMessagesAdapter.getView(ChatMessagesAdapter.java:70)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
      at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:712)
      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1609)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
      at ChatListView.onLayout(ChatListView.java:355)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:581)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1043)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1997)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1818)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
```